# How to read out of all lines in the .txt file specific fields required for the output?

Tags: android, text-files

I am new to android app development. need your help in solving this. I am not getting expected result. There are about 108 lines in my .txt file. It is only reading the same line for any given input. Wherhas it has to display the line according to the selected values by the user out of these 108 lines.

My textfile looks something like this

10

60

40

Z185-.......

10

60

50

Z186..

10

60

90

Z190-....

20

60

50

Z181-.... . . . .

35

75

100

Z,....

.

.
so on 108 lines

if user gives input values like this for petrol:10, diesel:60, air:40 then

Expected output:

```
Z185-...
```

Any help on this will be highly appreciated

here is the code

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private EditText editTextPetrol = null;

private EditText editTextDiesel = null;

private EditText editTextAir = null;

private TextView textViewResult = null;

private Button buttonSubmit = null;

private Context context = null;

FileOutputStream outputStream = null;

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );
    context = getApplicationContext();

    editTextPetrol = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.editTextPetrol );
    editTextDiesel = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.editTextDiesel );
    editTextAir = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.editTextAir );
    textViewResult = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.textViewResult );


    buttonSubmit = (Button) findViewById( R.id.buttonSubmit );

    buttonSubmit.setOnClickListener( new MyListener( editTextPetrol, editTextDiesel, editTextAir, textViewResult, context ) );
}

    private void writeFile(String filename, String data)
{

    try {
        outputStream = context.openFileOutput( filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE );
        outputStream.write( data.getBytes() );
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


class MyListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    private EditText editTextPetrol = null;
    private EditText editTextDiesel = null;
    private EditText editTextAir = null;
    private TextView textViewResult = null;
    private Context context = null;

    private String petrol = null;
    private String diesel = null;
    private String air = null;
    private String filename = null;
    private String result = null;

    MyListener(EditText editTextPetrol, EditText editTextDiesel, EditText editTextAir, TextView textViewResult, Context context) {
        this.editTextPetrol = editTextPetrol;
        this.editTextDiesel = editTextDiesel;
        this.editTextAir = editTextAir;
        this.textViewResult = textViewResult;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        petrol = editTextPetrol.getText().toString();
        diesel = editTextDiesel.getText().toString();
        air = editTextAir.getText().toString();
        filename = "file.txt";

        result = foo( filename, petrol, diesel, air );

        if (result == null) {
            result = "No entry found!";
        }

        textViewResult.setText( result );
    }


    File file = null;
    FileReader fileReader = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String currentPetrol = null, currentDiesel = null, currentAir = null, currentResult = null;


    private String foo (String filename,String petrol,String diesel,String air)
    {
        try {
            file = new File( context.getFilesDir(), filename );
            fileReader = new FileReader( file );
            br = new BufferedReader( fileReader );

            while (true) {
                currentPetrol = br.readLine();

                if (currentPetrol == null) {
                    currentResult = null;
                    break;
                }

                currentDiesel = br.readLine();

                if (currentDiesel == null) {
                    currentResult = null;
                    break;
                }

                currentAir = br.readLine();

                if (currentAir == null) {
                    currentResult = null;
                    break;
                }

                currentResult = br.readLine();

                if (currentResult == null) {
                    break;
                }

                if (currentPetrol.equals( petrol ) && currentDiesel.equals( diesel ) && currentAir.equals( air )) {
                    break;
                }
            }

            fileReader.close();
            br.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return currentResult;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example! The current is far away from minimal!

Answer (score 0):

The below code (**tested**) creates a file named `sample.txt` in `internal_storage` and tries to access `sample.txt` based on user inputs - `petrol, diesel & air` and finally displays the result on the screen.

**MainActivity.java** -

```
package com.example.sakethkatari.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private EditText editTextPetrol = null;
    private EditText editTextDiesel = null;
    private EditText editTextAir = null;
    private TextView textViewResult = null;
    private Button buttonSubmit = null;

    private Context context = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        context = getApplicationContext();
        createFile("sample.txt", "10\n20\n30\nSaketh\n40\n50\n60\nKatari\n");

        editTextPetrol = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPetrol);
        editTextDiesel = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextDiesel);
        editTextAir = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAir);
        textViewResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewResult);
        buttonSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSubmit);

        buttonSubmit.setOnClickListener( new MyListener(editTextPetrol, editTextDiesel, editTextAir, textViewResult, context) );
    }

    private void createFile(String filename, String data)
    {
        FileOutputStream fos = null;

        try
        {
            fos =context.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            fos.write( data.getBytes() );
            fos.close();
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class MyListener implements View.OnClickListener
{
    private EditText editTextPetrol = null;
    private EditText editTextDiesel = null;
    private EditText editTextAir = null;
    private TextView textViewResult = null;
    private  Context context = null;

    private String petrol = null;
    private String diesel = null;
    private String air = null;
    private String filename = null;
    private String result = null;

    MyListener(EditText editTextPetrol, EditText editTextDiesel, EditText editTextAir, TextView textViewResult, Context context)
    {
        this.editTextPetrol = editTextPetrol;
        this.editTextDiesel = editTextDiesel;
        this.editTextAir = editTextAir;
        this.textViewResult = textViewResult;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        petrol = editTextPetrol.getText().toString();
        diesel = editTextDiesel.getText().toString();
        air = editTextAir.getText().toString();
        filename = "sample.txt";

        result = foo(filename, petrol, diesel, air );

        if( result == null )
        {
            result = "No entry found!";
        }

        textViewResult.setText(result);
    }

    private String foo(String filename, String petrol, String diesel, String air)
    {
        FileReader fileReader = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String currentPetrol = null, currentDiesel = null, currentAir = null, currentResult = null;
        File file = null;


        try
        {
            file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), filename);
            fileReader = new FileReader(file);
            br = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

            while(true)
            {
                currentPetrol = br.readLine();

                if( currentPetrol == null )
                {
                    currentResult = null;
                    break;
                }

                currentDiesel = br.readLine();

                if( currentDiesel == null )
                {
                    currentResult = null;
                    break;
                }

                currentAir = br.readLine();

                if( currentAir == null )
                {
                    currentResult = null;
                    break;
                }

                currentResult = br.readLine();

                if( currentResult == null )
                {
                    break;
                }

                if( currentPetrol.equals(petrol) && currentDiesel.equals(diesel) && currentAir.equals(air) )
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            fileReader.close();
            br.close();
        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return currentResult;
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml** -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textViewPetrol"
        android:text="Petrol"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editTextPetrol"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textViewDiesel"
        android:text="Diesel"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editTextDiesel"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textViewAir"
        android:text="Air"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editTextAir"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textViewResult"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/buttonSubmit"
        android:text="Submit"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much but unfortunately when i click on button it is not displaying anything ..and foo is not readable .Please help me

Comment: Edited my answer, please check it and let me know if you have any more issues.

Comment: Hi,I tried with the edited code..but as soon as i give inputs and click submit button ..My app is getting stopped ..

Comment: I've tested the code, it's working. What are the inputs you've given? Also, what is `logcat` showing when your app is being terminated? yes, post your .txt file.

Comment: please find my txt file posted above..Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a `TextView` with id `textViewResult` in your `activity_main.xml`? Also, do you have this line of code - `textViewResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewResult);` in `MainActivity.java`?

Comment: yes thanks ..i missed it ..now if i give input values it is displaying no entry found..can you please tell how exactly i should give data \10\n..

Comment: I was creating `sample.txt` to test my code. So, now, remove the line (or comment it out) from where `createFile()` is being invoked. Secondly, inside `onClick()` method, update the filename to your `.txt` that is stored in the internal storage of your mobile.

Comment: Thank you so much..Now it is displaying output ..but it is reading only first line..inputs are 10,60,40 and output is Z185.. But what should i do In order to read all lines like if i gv inputs 10,60,50 expected output Z186..

Comment: `.txt file` -
`10
60
40
Z185
10
60
50
Z186`
Input `10, 60, 40` Output : `Z185`
Input `10, 60, 50` Output : `Z186`
That's what it is giving, right?

Comment: yes but when i give 10,60,50 it should give Z186 ..instead my ouput is "no entry found"

Comment: Can you provide the **exact** code that is producing the results you are saying?

Comment: Also, provide the updated `file.txt`. How are you writing content to the file? Is there some code that writes data to `file.txt`?

Comment: I posted my complete java code. No can you please help what i have to add to this code to read all lines from txtfile.  Exactly this is my problem everytime it is reading first line from txtfile..

Comment: I guess there is some problem in writing data to `file.txt`. Can you answer my question in the previous comment - `How are you writing content to the file?`?

Comment: Thanks a lot Saketh for your help :)  After few changes in my previous code its working now :)